# API postpayload include text variables

Tags: python, html, api

I am trying to add a text variable to a POST request and I wanted some suggestions on what I could be doing wrong.

The original code is in html, but I want to use it in python.

Here is the original HTML:

```
<form name="channel327911" action="https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Download.aspx"
 method="post">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Please enter your name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength=
"64" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Channel 01" />
    <input type="hidden" name="EntryID" value="327911" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tracking0" maxlength="64" />
</form>
```

Here is my python code:

```
import requests

json_payload = {
"EntryID": "327911",
"tracking0": "64"
}

requestlink = requests.post(url = "https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Download.aspx", data = json_payload)
stuff = requestlink.content

with open("supportlmi.exe", 'wb') as s:
    s.write(stuff)
```

problem is if I try to add the `name` to the post' body like so:

```
import requests

json_payload = {
"name": "Conglomo - Rocko"
"EntryID": "327911",
"tracking0": "64"
}

requestlink = requests.post(url = "https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Download.aspx", data = json_payload)
stuff = requestlink.content

with open("supportlmi.exe", 'wb') as s:
    s.write(stuff)
```

Then it will error out.
I figure there must be a way to pass the name into the body as you are able to do it in html using the form.

NOTE: YOU CAN USE THE HTML CODE ABOVE AND IT SHOULD WORK. I PUT IN LOGMEIN's TEST SUPPORT GROUP SO YOU CAN ACTUALLY TRY THIS IN HTML :)

EDIT: The result should be a download of Logmein's launcher. Not a status code.

I actually figured out a work around for this issue! Instead of putting the `name` in the body, you append the name to the url itself like so; `https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Download.aspx?name=Conglomo%20Rocko` With doing that, I don't need to put the name in the body. The result is an exe download of Logmein's launcher! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
import requests

payload = {
"EntryID": "327911",
"tracking0": "64",
"name": "Conglomo - Rocko"
}

response = requests.post("https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Download.aspx", json=payload)
stuff = response.content

print(stuff)
print(response.status_code)
```

You need to pass the payload as `json` to the request

Comment: I apologize as I should have mentioned that the result will be a download file. Technically it would give you a status code back but it wouldn't give the download. Instead it probably redirected to the download webpage instead of actually downloading the file. I actually figured out how to get the name in the request. I updated my post to reflect the information. However I will most likely give you the answer as you were nice enough to try and help out. Much appreciated